# Lie groups and vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Suppose we have the group of affine transformations of the real line.

Our group consists of all $2\times2$ matrices of the form:
$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$ where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and $a>0$.

What is the way to find the basis for left-invariant vector fields?

Thanks.

Comment: See also the links at the [previous related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3441155/checking-a-group-is-a-lie-group#comment7074491_3441155).

Answer (score 2):

Let $g=\begin{bmatrix} a&b\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$. The left-invariant $1$-forms are given by the entries of the matrix $g^{-1}dg = \begin{bmatrix} da/a & db/a \\ 0&0\end{bmatrix}$. What are the dual vector fields?

Alternatively, find the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ (i.e., $T_IG$), take an obvious basis, and left-translate it.